# UIPopoverController on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableView` cell with several `UITextField`s in it. When a user clicks into one of the textFields, a popover appears with some information. At first, they then had to click outside of either the textField or the popover to clear the popover before then clicking into the next textField. I therefore then added the cell's `contentView` to the popover controller's `passThroughViews` property so they can click through the different textFields in that cell at will without having to dismiss the popover controller first. However, it keeps the original popover open (which) is fine, and then opens another identical popover as well.

Is there a way I can tell if a popover is already open before sending the command to open another? I can't think of how to detect this?

Comment: Does each cell control its own popover?

Comment: just to be clear...Each cell is the same Custom UITableView cell and will call the same UIPopoverController but then populate it with different data (relevant to that cell). The UIPopoverController is an ivar so I have tried using retain counts, but it appears that even if you click out of it, its retain count stays at 1 (presumably until you release it in dealloc).

Comment: Retain counts are useless;  any reasoning about memory management using raw retain counts is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @bbum I added your suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did it. For others who find this question. In addition to the other answers, this is how I did it.

I made my view controller a `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`.

I then created an `BOOL` called `myPopoverControllerOpen`.

When I created my popover I set the `BOOL` to yes. Using the delegate method `popoverDidDismissPopover` I then set the `BOOL` back to `NO`.

I then check on the state of this `BOOL` before presenting the popover.

Answer (score 2):

If each cell controls the logic of the popover, you need to say to your custom cell to implement `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol, set the delegate for the popover as `self` (the cell) and override `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover` like the following:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self.pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; // hide the popover
    self.pop = nil; // release the popover, this forces to create a fresh popover each time
}
```

If you want you can also remove the line `self.pop = nil;` but remember to release it in `dealloc` (I suppose you are not using ARC code since you are using `retainCount`). As **bbum** suggested you should't use `retainCount` to check objects existence.

In addition, each `UIPopoverController` instance has a property called `popoverVisible` if you want to see if a popover is already visible or not.